# Python: for loop with counter and scheduled increase in increase

Tags: python, loops, counter

Python Learner. Working on a recurring monthly deposit, interest problem. Except I am being asked to build in a raise after every 6th month in this hypothetical. I am reaching the goal amount in fewer months than I'm supposed to.

Currently using the % function along with += function

```
annual_salary = float(input("What is your expected Income? "))                  
portion_saved = float(input("What percentage of your income you expect to save? "))
total_cost = float(input("what is the cost of your dream home? "))
semi_annual_raise = float(input("Enter your expected raise, as a decimal "))

monthly_salary = float(annual_salary/12)
monthly_savings = monthly_salary * portion_saved
down_payment= total_cost*.25
           
savings = 0
for i in range(300):
    savings = monthly_savings*(((1+.04/12)**i) - 1)/(.04/12)
    if float(savings) >= down_payment:
            break
    if i % 6 == 0 :
        monthly_salary += monthly_salary * .03
        monthly_savings = monthly_salary * portion_saved
```

Comment: What is your expected results. And whats 'n'

Comment: What's the monthly_savings value, what's the r, and how many months do you expect it would take?

Comment: Reached savings goal in 115 months rather than 142 months. Added context to the original post. Thank you.

Comment: Should you be factoring a raise in the very first month? When 'i' is 0, monthly_salary will be updated. Range(1, 301) will fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this work for you? Typically, we want to use `while` loops over `for` loops when we don't know how many iterations the loop will ultimately need.

```
monthly_savings = 1.1 # saving 10% each month
monthly_salary = 5000
down_payment = 2500
interest = .02
savings = 0
months = 0

while savings < goal:
    print(savings)
    savings = (monthly_salary * monthly_savings) + (savings * interest)
    months += 1
    
    if months % 6 == 0 :
        monthly_salary += monthly_salary * .03
        
print("Took " + str(months) + " to save enough")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice all. My code is getting clearer and I reached correct outputs! The problem was with how and when I was calculating interest. In the case of a static contribution I successfully used the formula for interest on a recurring deposit, here, the simpler move of calculating interest at each month was needed to work with the flow of the loop.

```
annual_salary = float(input("What is your expected Income? "))                  
portion_saved = float(input("What percentage of your income you expect to save? "))
total_cost = float(input("what is the cost of your dream home? "))
semi_annual_raise = float(input("Enter your expected raise, as a decimal "))
monthly_salary = float(annual_salary/12)
monthly_savings = monthly_salary * portion_saved
down_payment = total_cost*.25

savings = 0
month = 1
while savings < down_payment :
    print(savings)
    savings += monthly_savings
    savings = savings * (1+(.04/12))
    month += 1  

    if month % 6 == 0 :
            monthly_salary += (monthly_salary * semi_annual_raise)
            monthly_savings = (monthly_salary * portion_saved)

print("")
print("it will take " + str(month) + " months to meet your savings goal.")
```